# Tortoise SVN - Client side pre commit hook to include specific file in commit

Tags: c#, svn, tortoisesvn, pre-commit-hook

I am using Tortoise SVN tool on the client side to commit the codes.

I have a precommit hook in C# that will be called before user commit the code in to SVN on the client side.

During precommit hook execution, I have modified some files in the hook and I want to include the same in the commit.

I used the following code to get the list of files going to commit

```
string[] files = File.ReadAllLines(args[0]);
```

I tried including the modified file path in the same location (args[0]) but the file was not included in the commit.

Please suggest a way to include the file in the transaction..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your problem description is very unclear to me. Are you trying to add a new file to a commit through one of TSVNs commit hooks? If so, you might look into using the Start-commit hook, which should allow modifications to the list of files to commit. Although, i can't recall whether such modifications would be limited only to removals or whether inclusions of addtional files would be supported/allowed :(

Comment: @elgonzo Your understanding is right.  I want the files to be changed and included only before transaction.  "Start commit" will not work for me as user may (or) may not commit the code.

Comment: Why should "Start commit" not work? Why would it matter whether the user actually commits to the commit or not? (sorry for the bad pun).

Comment: @elgonzo, I used to update the transaction changes in a text file including the revision and log messages given.  If it is "start commit", I'm unsure on when the user actually commit the code by clicking "OK".

Comment: I am confused, as i don't know how that text file you just mentioned relates to the file(s) you want to add to the commit. You would not need to add text file(s) that just contains information about the commit history. The SVN repository already (naturally) contains and maintains this information...

Comment: @elgonzo.  Understood, this is a kind of tracking purpose for internal use which we follow.  So whenever client commit any code, hook has to get the Rev, log message and append those details in a text file.  This file needs to go along with same commit.  Hope Im clear

Comment: To my knowledge this is not possible with TSVN (or the standard svn command line tool). Not sure either whether server-side hook scripts might allow altering of an transaction. I would suggest (if possible) to debate a different tracking procedure (using the SVN log) for your internal use. If you already execute on this internal tracking procedure and dont want to/cannot change it, i suggest to stick with the tools you currently use that enabled you to do the tracking in this particular way...